# not able create recursine build in pnpm repo while building up docker image

Tags: docker, pnpm

### => ERROR [stage-0  6/11] RUN pnpm run -r build                         1.0s

> [stage-0  6/11] RUN pnpm run -r build:
> 0.907  ERROR  Expected pattern to be a non-empty string
> 0.907

when to run pnpm run -r build  normally its working fine.  Thanks in advance!

pnpm run -r build  shoud be success as a part of docker building step